# How enable/disable item in contextmenu

Tags: android

I can disable a item in the contextmenu with this:

```
menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
```

in the onCreateContextMenu, but what if I later would like to set it to true within the same activity? How can I do that during runtime?

EDIT:

```
        // Create context menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for this image"); // Title for the menu
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_1_menu, menu);

    menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);  
}
```

This is where I want to change the item to enable:

```
    // Handle return values from different activities
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            // Get value from intent
            String imageId = data.getExtras().getString("imageId");

            // Show full screen image
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        else if(requestCode == 2) {
            String contact1 = data.getExtras().getString("contactName");
            String contact2 = data.getExtras().getString("test");
            Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, "" + "Value from activity 3: " + contact1 + " " + contact2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


 CHANGE MENU ITEM 1 TO ENABLE HERE!!!!

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to option menus where you need the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method to add your menu specific code that should be executed each time the menu is showing, you can do this in `onCreateContextMenu` for context menus. `onCreateContextMenu` is called each time the menu is going to show on the screen.

So just store the enabled state for your menu somewhere and use this variable to set the enabled state accordingly in the `onCreateContextMenu` method. For your example this would look like

```
boolean menuItem1EnabledState = false;

// Create context menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for this image"); // Title for the menu
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_1_menu, menu);

    menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(menuItem1EnabledState);  
}


// Handle return values from different activities
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            // Get value from intent
            String imageId = data.getExtras().getString("imageId");

            // Show full screen image
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        else if(requestCode == 2) {
            String contact1 = data.getExtras().getString("contactName");
            String contact2 = data.getExtras().getString("test");
            Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, "" + "Value from activity 3: " + contact1 + " " + contact2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            menuItem1EnabledState = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can see here [link](http://phpidiots.in/uncategorized/changing-menu-items-at-runtime/) to get proper information.
basically code sniipet

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_my_item);

    if (myItemShouldBeEnabled) {
        item.setEnabled(true);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
    } else {
        // disabled
        item.setEnabled(false);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(130);
    }
}
```

makes icon little bit fad.

enjoy your code:)

Answer (score 0):

You should write the code to enable/disable the options menu in [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) as clearly mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu).

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (yourConditionIsSatisfied)
        {
            menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
        } else
        {
            menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In pre honeycomb, you just need to change the value of `yourConditionIsSatisfied` as `true/false` and nothing else. You need not worry if it will be triggered or not, because `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is **ALWAYS** triggered when you click the options button. But in case of higher versions of OSsyou need to call the [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29). `invalidateOptionsMenu()` will in turn trigger the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. As per your code given, you should write the following code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {

            if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                // Get value from intent
                String imageId = data.getExtras().getString("imageId");
                // Show full screen image
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                // Add new menu item for context menu of the imageview
                // Write
            } else if (requestCode == 2)
            {
                String contact1 = data.getExtras().getString("contactName");
                String contact2 = data.getExtras().getString("test");
                Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, "" + "Value from activity 3: " + contact1 + " " + contact2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                conditionSatisfied = true;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }
    }



@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (conditionSatisfied)
        {
            menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
        } else
        {
            menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have already read that page a couple of times, but I don't get it where I should place the onPrepareOptionsMenu method to get it to work!? I think it's asking for the Menu object

Comment: The onPrepareOptionsMenu() can be placed anywhere in your activity and it will be called automatically, just as onCreateContextMenu is called automatically when the context options are about to be displayed.

Comment: Yes but how do I change the item to be enabled during runtime?

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! But I still don't get it! I wonder how I should trigger this? I thought if I used yourConditionIsSatisfied = true; somewhere in the code it would work!? But I guess that's wrong. How to trigger?

Comment: Check my updated answer, I modified according to your given code!

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, but it still doesn't work! And I also get a red line below invalidateOptionsMenu(); with this error message: The method invalidateOptionsMenu() is undefined for the type Activity_1 . Almost there! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25143/discussion-between-antrromet-and-3d-kreativ)

Answer (score 0):

Use onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(true);
    return true;
}
```

Also On Android 3.0 and higher, you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() when you want to update the menu, because the menu is always open. The system will then call onPrepareOptionsMenu() so you can update the menu items.

Comment: OK, but I wonder how to call this method and be able to pass the Menu object during runtime? I want the menu item to be enabled.

Comment: you will be overriding activity method no need to call it it will be called by itself...  and in android 3.0 or higher call invalidateOptionsMenu when u want to update menu .. and to enable item call setEnabled(true) on menuitem

Comment: Hmm! Could you be kind and just add some code? It's easier for me to understand. I'm using a device running in 2.3.6 but I want the code to also work on higher version. Do I need to do check what version of if also use this method for version 3.0 and higher? Preciate some code to understand better! Thanks! :)

Comment: copy paste above code in your activity and also post your oncreateoptionsmenu code here in question as well.. so i can post better code relating to your items/code