# Context Menu item hide based on list view item

Tags: android, contextmenu

I've been developing an application which store some itens on a list view. Some of this itens have a type (Normal and Traffic Based Event). I need to set visible a item of the context menu (View Traffic) when the type of the element stored in the list view is equal to Traffic Based Event.

I tried to place the condition (Menuitem.setVisible(true)) into the methods onCreateContextMenu and onContextItemSelected, but none of them worked. Else I read some post here at stack overflow which didn't helped.

[Set visibility in Menu programmatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030268/set-visibility-in-menu-programatically-android)

[How enable/disable item in contextmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086838/how-enable-disable-item-in-contextmenu)

Someone know if there is a way to do that?

EDIT: 
I've tried to use one method cited on the second post and it set visible the menu item. I still need to get the position of the item that was deep clicked on the list view to get its type.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.getItem(2).setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getItem(int), you can get the item using its id. For example:

`menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings)`